# Looking for counter example where monotone convergence sequence not hold for a decreasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

Let $\{f_n\}$ be an increasing sequence of nonnegative measurable functions on $E$. The monotone convergence sequence then states that:

If $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise almost everyhwere on $E$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_E f_n = \int_E f$.

Why does this theorem not hold for decreasing sequences of functions? I'm baffled why it wouldn't, since I feel like everything would be symmetric in a way or whatever... Does anyone have an explicit counter example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take the sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}$ on $[0,+\infty)$

Comment: Let me just add (for  OP's sake) that if one of the functions $f_n$ is integrable then  $\int f_n d\mu$ does tend to $\int f d\mu$,

Comment: Interesting... So the sequence Marios gave me consists of non-integrable functions?